# Export curve / path from blender to Three.js

Tags: export, blender

I asked this question on stackoverflow but I got send here, so here it goes:

I have a very simple scene and I want to export a bezier curve / nurbs curve to JSON. Nothing I do seems to export anything. I can export meshes etc.

I'm sure I have done this in the past but I have no idea how to do it anymore.

Thanx a lot!

Answer (score 0):

From what it looks like you need to add something to your Blender installation.

[This Video Tutorial on YT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pp02jQp20is) might help you out.

In addition there are multiple [Extensions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9305/export-bezier-curves) available as well [Scripts (from the above video)](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender).

So you will probably need to use some kind of script/extension for Blender to export in the appropriate format.